# Why does a higher pixel density device have less screen real estate? (Eclipse AVD)

Tags: android, resolution, android-virtual-device, dpi, pixel

In Eclipse's AVD, I've created two devices that are identical except for their density values. Device 1 has has an `abstracted LCD density` of 240; device 2 has 160. The resolution for both is 480x800.

Can someone explain to me why elements on device 1's screen looks "bigger"? Since they have the same resolution, shouldn't they be showing the same number of pixels? If anything, since device 1 has a higher density, shouldn't it show *more* details/screen real estate?

**Device 1**

[image: Device_1_Screenshot]

**Device 2**

[image: Device_2_Screenshot]

<sub>Screeshots - (Click for larger variant)</sub>

As shown above, I'm drawing a circle with a radius of 15dp at a random screen position on both devices. The circle is definitely smaller on device 2, as is the action bar. Why is this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are drawing with *dp*, not physical pixels. *dp* try to abstract from the physical size and give the user a GUI element of the same physical size. So if the pixels on one device are *smaller* you need to use more physical pixels to obtain the same effect as on a device with bigger pixels.

So:
800 pixel / 240 pixel per inch = 3 1/3 inch (physical length of that screen dimension). Size of one pixel: 1 pixel / 240 pixel per inch = 0,004 inch.
800 pixel / 160 pixel per inch = 5 inch. Size of one pixel: 1 pixel / 160 pixel per inch = 0,006 inch.

So with the same resolution (number of pixels) the pixels in the lower density device are significantilly bigger (around 50% bigger in each dimension). So you need *less* physical pixel to draw the circle to show the circle with 15 dp.

Simply said: Low dpi means bigger pixel. Same resolution (number of pixel) means lower dpi device has a bigger screen.

So on physical devices these circles have the same physical size on devices with different size. But your emulator windows have the *same* size, for speed reasons one physical pixel is mapped to one physical pixel on your computer screen. So you are using *less* pixel on the low dpi device but paint them with same-size physical pixels. Solution: You need to resize the emulator window so it matches the *real* size. I just don't have access to my Android SDK installation but IIRC you can set the (computer) screen dpi in the AVD launch options so the size will be set automatically.

Here are the images scaled to retain the proportion of the real devices:

[image: 160 dpi device]
[image: 240 dpi devce]

As you can see the circles have the same physical size, as have the action bar, the icon and the status bar.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. I launched each device with `screen size` settings to match your answer (e.g. [device 1](http://i.imgur.com/KsZCQ), [device 2](http://i.imgur.com/lNUon.png)). But this produced two emulator windows of similar size, unlike the differently-sized emulator windows in your answer. I then proceeded to re-launch them both but with the same `monitor dpi` value and that produced emulator windows more like your answer. Does that sound right to you? Should I always set all of my AVDs to have the same `monitor dpi`?

Comment: No, there is not much use of using the correct monitor dpi all the time. The result would be that the window has the right size that matches the real device's size. But what is the use of that? You need the emulator for checking if the layout works on device classes you don't own, but for testing the UX you need real devices. As a tradeoff scaled emulator windows will look smudgy like my second image as they normally are scaled down; your monitor most likely has *less* dpi than a phone (100-120 dpi in contrast to at least 160 upto ~300).

Comment: Good point. But by matching the emulator window sizes to real device sizes, doesn't it allow you to check that UI elements expressed in density-independent pixels are the same physical size on all devices? For example, I defined all circles to have a radius of 15dp, so all circles will be the same physical size regardless of the device. Having matching emulator window sizes allows you to check whether that is really the case, does it not?

Comment: Do you want to debug the Android SDK and the emulator or your own application?

Comment: @his I am facing the same problem. But I am not able to understand how to solve this problem. Could you please more explain how to solve this problem so the views dont look bigger in lower density devices

Comment: @nads What problem exactly? If you want to check the "real" size on screen then you can check "Scale display to real size" and enter your screen's dpi when starting the virtual device. But as the computer screen dpi probably is lower than the device dpi you get a smudgy image with loss of pixels. And you still don't get the feel of the real device. Unless you want to compare two different devices on screen there is not much use of this.